# Python exception handling 'as' keyword

Tags: python, class, exception

The following code

```
try:
    a = 10
    b = 0
    c = a/b
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(e)
```

gives the output

```
division by zero
```

I can not seem to find any information regarding how the 'as' keyword gets the ouptut string from the ZeroDivisionError class or its parent classes.
What exactly is e an alias for?

Tried looking for an explanation on the docs but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Answer (score 4):

The `as` keyword is simply part of the syntax for binding the raised exception to a local variable. Here, `e` is bound to the exception object. The "output string" comes from the fact that builtin exceptions like `ZeroDivisionError` define a `__str__` method that returns the exception's message.

Per [8.3 Exception Hanlding](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) from the Python tutorial:

> The except clause may specify a variable after the exception name. The variable is bound to the exception instance which typically has an `args` attribute that stores the arguments. For convenience, builtin exception types define `__str__()` to print all the arguments without explicitly accessing `.args`.
>
> ```py
> try:
>    raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
> except Exception as inst:
>    print(type(inst))    # the exception instance
>    print(inst.args)     # arguments stored in .args
>    print(inst)          # __str__ allows args to be printed directly,
>                         # but may be overridden in exception subclasses>
>    x, y = inst.args     # unpack args
>    print('x =', x)
>    print('y =', y)
> ```
>
> ```
> <class 'Exception'>
> ('spam', 'eggs')
> ('spam', 'eggs')
> x = spam
> y = eggs
> ```